# Is there a way to reload initializers automatically for rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I play with RailsAdmin right now.

RailsAdmin DSL configuration are stored in initializers. There is a way to keep them in model, but I believe it's bad idea (to store view related info in the model).

So, each time when I have to change it, I have to restart rails server, which is quite annoying.

Is there a way to enable autoreload for initializers?

Comment: See documentation here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to:-Reloading-RailsAdmin-Config-Automatically. Feels hacky, but I've used it in the past.

Comment: @DamienRoche: Please, can you post it as the answer, so I can accept it. I believe we did this once already :)

Comment: Could you show me how is your model? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the documentation [here](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to:-Reloading-RailsAdmin-Config-Automatically):

In your `/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb` you should add `config.parent_controller = ApplicationController.to_s`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :reload_rails_admin if :rails_admin_path?

  private

  def reload_rails_admin
    models = %W(User UserProfile)

    models.each do |m|
      RailsAdmin::Config.reset_model(m)
    end

    RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.reset

    load("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb")
  end

  def rails_admin_path?
    controller_path =~ /rails_admin/ && Rails.env == "development"
  end

end
```

It does feel very hacky and I'd love to hear of a better alternative.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Could you show me how is your model? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this file
`config/initializers/rails_admin_reload.rb`

```rb
# See also: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to:-Reloading-RailsAdmin-Config-Automatically#alternative-method-for-the-railsadmin-versions-that-does-not-extend-applicationcontroller
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  RailsAdmin::ApplicationController.class_eval do
    before_action :reload_rails_admin, if: :reload_rails_admin? # Reloading RailsAdmin Config Automatically

    RAILS_ADMIN_FILE_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb"

    class << self
      def fetch_rails_admin_file_updated_time
        File::Stat.new(RAILS_ADMIN_FILE_PATH).mtime
      end
      attr_accessor :__file_timestamp
    end
    @__file_timestamp = fetch_rails_admin_file_updated_time

    def reload_rails_admin
      RailsAdmin::Config.reset

      load(RAILS_ADMIN_FILE_PATH)
    end

    def reload_rails_admin?
      return false unless Rails.env.development?
      begin
        file_updated_at = RailsAdmin::ApplicationController.fetch_rails_admin_file_updated_time
        has_changed = file_updated_at != self.class.__file_timestamp
        return has_changed
      ensure
        self.class.__file_timestamp = file_updated_at
      end
    end
  end
end
```